# Run bootable ubuntu setup on ubuntu machine without internet

Tags: 14.04, usb-creator

Referring to https://askubuntu.com/questions/564844/accidently-removed-the-network-drivers, and more than 20 hours of fixing, I found it more quick to re-install ubuntu. Successfully created the setup by following http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu and now need to make the usb bootable without using internet on ubuntu machine. Any related help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the Ubuntu image, you can create a bootable usb using a tool like [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

If you don't, I believe it can also download the iso's automatically for you when you choose what OS you want the drive to have. Obviously, that would need to be done on a machine with internet access, like where you posted from.

Comment: yes, i have iso on ubuntu machine right now.

Comment: these are window based installer. I created ubuntu based installer but the question is how to boot ubuntu from usb. like we boot windows machine with usb device etc. Is there any short key for ubuntu machine?